# How to expel specified buffer cache of raw device

Tags: file, caching, operating-system, buffer

When I open a file through a file system and write data to it, the page buffer about this file will be automatically expelled if the file is deleted.

If I open a raw device and write a lot of data to it, the memory buffer holds all the data even if some of the data I have discarded.
I cannot close the raw device or other ways to empty the buffer because I still want other data retaining there.

Is there any method to achieve this?

Comment: How do you "delete" data from a raw device?

Comment: I cannot delete data from a raw device. I manage the data in a "logical way", saying, using a bitmap to indicate which block has been "deleted".

Comment: Maybe the question comes to that how to expel the page buffer holding a specified block of an open file?